# How to manually focus input

Tags: html, vue.js

I want to replicate a common item list renaming feature, where you have a list of layers and if you double click a layer, it changes the layer item to an input and that input is automatically focused with its text selected as well.

In my example, I am not able to `focus()` the DOM element by its `ref` because it says it is not defined. It only works if I click a second time on the element once its changed to an input. How do I set this autofocus?

```
  <div v-for="(item, i) in items">
      <div @click="changeToInput(i)" v-if="!item.input">{{item.name}}</div>
      <input ref="input" v-model="item.name" onfocus="select()" v-else>
    </div>
```

```
 changeToInput(i) {
      this.items[i].input = true;
      //this.$refs.input.focus()
 }
```

Here is the complete example : https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-khayyam-2x8mp?file=/src/App.vue:481-573

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Two solutions:**

**First one**: uses `v-if` + `this.$nextTick`:

`v-if` will insert/destroy the component when the binding expression is true/false, so in current cycle, `input` hasn't been in Dom tree. You have to use `nextTick` to wait for next cycle to get the Dom element of Input. And `this.$refs.input` will be one array based on how many `v-if=true`, so you have to filter out the `this.items` to find out correct index (that is why I used one combination of Array.slice and Array.filter).

**Updated**: The order of the elements of `this.$refs.input1` is the order VNode is created. For example: clicks input2 -> input3 -> input1, the order of `this.$refs.input1` is [2, 3, 1], not [1, 2, 3].

**Second one**: uses `v-show` + `this.$nextTick`:

It will make things easier, because `v-show` only update the css styles for Dom elements, it will not add/remove component instance (Vnode) from VNode tree. So the `this.$refs.input` will always equal `this.items.length`.

```js
new Vue ({
  el:'#app',
  data() {
    return {
      items1: [
        { name: "Joe", input: false },
        { name: "Sarah", input: false },
        { name: "Jeff", input: false }
      ],
      items2: [
        { name: "Joe", input: false },
        { name: "Sarah", input: false },
        { name: "Jeff", input: false }
      ],
      refSort: {}
    };
  },
  methods: {
    changeToInput1(i) {
      this.items1[i].input = true;
      let refCount = (this.$refs.input1 && this.$refs.input1.length) || 0
      refCount < this.items1.length && (this.refSort[i] = refCount)
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        // the purpose uses this.refSort is record the order of this.$refs.input (Its order is same as the creating order of Ref), you can uncomment below line to see the root cause
        //console.log(this.$refs.input1[0] && this.$refs.input1[0].value, this.$refs.input1[1] && this.$refs.input1[1].value, this.$refs.input1[2] && this.$refs.input1[2].value)
        this.$refs.input1[this.refSort[i]].focus()
      })
    },
    changeToInput2(i) {
      this.items2[i].input = true;
      this.$nextTick(() => this.$refs.input2[i].focus())
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
  <div id="app">
    <h3>Uses v-if: <p>{{items1}}</p></h3>
    <div v-for="(item, i) in items1">
      <div @click="changeToInput1(i)" v-if="!item.input">{{item.name}}</div>
      <input ref="input1" v-model="item.name" onfocus="select()" v-else>
    </div>
    <h3>Uses v-show: <p>{{items2}}</p></h3>
    <div v-for="(item, i) in items2">
      <div @click="changeToInput2(i)" v-show="!item.input">{{item.name}}</div>
      <input ref="input2" v-model="item.name" onfocus="select()" v-show="item.input">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot, great answer. The second option makes more sense, although the `focus()` doesn't seem to work like the first one.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why, but it works when I put `this.$refs.input2[i].focus()` inside a `$nextTick`. Even if the input should already have been in the DOM.

Comment: my mistake, the `focus` in second solution is not working because the input element is not visible when `v-show=true`, so have to wait for next Dom update cycle. Already correct both two solutions, they should be fine now